# Gatsby image fluid stretches to beyond the vertical size of the container

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm building a gatsby site to show my photographs. I want a full-screen page for each photograph, and the photo should fill out the page, but respecting the aspect ratio.

The problem is that while photos shot in landscape orientation are limited correctly, photos shot in portrait orientation fill out all horizontal space but overflows the vertical space.

In [the documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/#avoiding-stretched-images-using-the-fluid-type) there is the statement

> As mentioned previously, images using the fluid type are stretched to match the container’s width and height

However, my observed behavior is that it only stretches to match the width, not height.

I simplified my problem into this small example, that tries to contain the images in a 400x400px container:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

export default (props) => {
  const { data } = props;
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div style={{height: "400px", width: "400px", background: "white" }}>
        <Img fluid={ data.file.childImageSharp.fluid } />
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query($id: String!) {
    file(id: { eq: $id }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 500, fit: INSIDE) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

In the landscape example, the image is constrained to the width of the containing div:
[image: Landscape example]

In the portrait orientation example, the image fills out the entire width of the containing div, becoming too high:

[image: Portrait orientation example]

How do I make Gatsby Image scale down to also be restrained to the available vertical space?

p.s. the rounded corners in the example images are remnants of a bootstrap class from an older solution, but its presence did not affect the problem in question.

Comment: Do you want the images to be 400px x 400px?

Comment: No, that was just to exemplify that the image stretches outside the container when it's in the portrait orientation, but is kept inside the container when it's in the landscape orientation. However, I seem to have figured it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that if I add `height` and `object-fit` CSS properties to the `<Img />` tag, it works as I intend. (in Firefox and Chrome)

```
<Img
  style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}
  imgStyle={{ objectFit: "contain" }}
  fluid={ data.file.childImageSharp.fluid }
/>
```

This gives the intended result, both in my simplified example, but also in the actual flex-box based layout.